# how to color a particular part of image in photoshop

Tags: image, photoshop

Hi guys I am new to photoshop I have spirit image here which has multiple images in same images for example I have cart image here alongside of phone call image. I just want to change the color of cart to red.. I have photoshop and went through tutorials but hue/saturation doesn't help  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVQnL.png)

can someone help me or provide me steps how to change color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshot seems to show that your sprite image is a transparent PNG, so you can click the [Lock Transparent Pixels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7Tzu.png) button on the Layers panel on the right.  Then you can pick the color red you want in the Color Picker and use the Brush tool to paint only the cart.

Comment: If I lock transparent pixels then my brush is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can select just one image, or a specific part of a larger image, by using the 'magic wand' tool.

Click this icon, or the icon most similar to it in Photoshop:
[Magic Wand Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67yEh.gif)

Then select your shopping cart by clicking on a portion of it which is colored, then you'll be able to change the color with the paint bucket tool, or by using the menu at the top of the screen.

You'd click 'Edit' then 'Fill' to fill your selection with the color chosen in your color picker currently.

Comment: when I click on magic wand tool it selects all other icons too

Answer (score 0):

For changing a color you have to go to right footer and there you'll see `fx` (Add a layer style) -> Color Overlay.

From there you can  change the color of your cart
For reference I am attaching the images.

**Fx Menu**
[image: Fx Option]

**Color Overlay**
[image: Color Overlay]